# Create List from WebAPI JSON data using React? Map is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a list from webAPI data that is returned in JSON format. I have a file that connects to the API, a file that calls the method and then my nav.js file.

api file:

````
export default axios.create({
     baseURL: 'http:/server:3500/api';
)}
```
call to the web app file, this has all of the service CRUD operations
```
const GetAllCars= () => {
     return db.get('/Cars');
}
```
my nav componet
```
import CarDataService from '/Cars';
const CarLeftNav = () =>
{
    const [ carList, setCarList ] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
          CarDataService.GetAllCars()
            .then((response) => {
               setCarList(response.data); 
           })
           .catch((e) => {
             console.log(e);
           }
     });
   


     return {
         <ul>
            { carList.map((data) => (
               <li key={data.Id}>{ data.CarModel } </li>
             )}
       }

}
export default CarLeftNav
````

am I missing something or is there a different way to accomplish this?

I'm learning React and I'm able to bind a grid in a similiar call in the useEffect method, but I'm not able to bind the data to a LI list.

Comment: Did you log the response from the api? Also it would be good to initialize the state of the carList as an empty array

Comment: If I do console.log(response.data) I get [ object Object ] back, however, if I go to Network (in dev tools), I can see the  carList has the data from the API in JSON format

Comment: So it's not an array, it's an object, and objects don't have a map method, hence the error.

Comment: What does `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))` emit?

Comment: @rayhatfield it shows my data like so: {
      “data”: [{
                 “carId”: 1,
        “carModel” : “Ford”
      },
    {
          “carId”: 2,
        “carModel” : “Chevy”


    },
   {
                 “carId”: 3,
        “carModel” : “Nissan”
  

   }
]
}

Comment: What I think is happening here is that `response.data` gets you that object, and that object has its own `data` property. So you'd need to either change it to `setCarList(response.data.data)` or `carList.data.map(...)`

Comment: setCarList(response.data.data) worked, then I did { carList.map(data) => ....  and they appear now. Been trying to figure this out for 2 days. The crazy thing is, I'm calling the same function to load a grid (react-data-table) and no issues. Guess that component has all of this stuff in the code.